# Undefined variable Error when try to access PHP class variable in function

Tags: php

I have run into a problem. My php class structure is as follows:

```
    class CustomerDao{
...
var $lastid;

  function insertUser($user)
  {
    ...
    $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
    return 0;
  }
      function getCustId()
  { 
    return $lastid; 
  }
    }
```

When i use this class, it let me access $lastid varibale in first function "insertUser", but it throws an error when i use $lastid in second function. I have no idea how to resolve this problem. Please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first function you are creating a new variable called `$lastid` which exists only within the scope of the function. In the second function this fails because there is no `$lastid` variable declared within this function.

To access a class member you use the notation `$this->lastid`.

```
class CustomerDao {
    ...
    var $lastid;

    function insertUser($user)
    {
        ...
        $this->lastid = mysql_insert_id();
        return 0;
    }

    function getCustId()
    { 
        return $this->lastid; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked!!! Actually i was making mistake of using $this like:
$this->$lastid;
I corrected like this:
$this->lastid;
Thank You so much.

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to access a class variable, which is done like this instead:

```
function getCustId() { 
    return $this->lastid; 
}
```

Comment: When i used $this with return statment it gives me this error:
Cannot access empty property!!!

Comment: Make sure you don't put a dollar sign in front of the property name when using `$this`. So NOT like this: `$this->$lastid`, but do it like this: `$this->lastid`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change an object property, you want [the `this` keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

```
$this->lastid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Reference: [PHP Manual: Classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 3):

Your code sample should look this:

```
class CustomerDao{
...
var $lastid;

  function insertUser($user)
  {
    ...
    $this->lastid = mysql_insert_id();
    return 0;
  }
      function getCustId()
  { 
    return $this->lastid; 
  }
    }
```

You need to reference the class (`$this`) to access its `$lastid` property. So it should be `$this->lastid`;

Answer (score 2):

to use a class variable inside the class use the `$this` keyword

so to use `$lastid` variable inside class use `$this->lastid`

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is this:

```
function insertUser($user) {
  ...
  $this->lastid = mysql_insert_id();
  return 0;
}

function getCustId() { 
  return $this->lastid; 
}
```

Note the this-keyword. Your first function works, because you assign a new (local!) variable `$lastid` within your `insertUser()` function - but it has nothing to do with the class property `$lastid`.